# System apparently doesn't recognize USB microphone input

Tags: usb, microphone, input-devices

I purchased an Audio Technica USB microphone a while ago, but my system doesn't recognise input into it.

When I plug it in and open Audacity, I see the microphone input options (such as '*ATR USB Microphone: USB audio (hr:1,0): Line:1'*). However, whenever I try to record anything I only wind up with only a flat line (indicating that there's no input).

arecord -L gives this:

```
default
    Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
sysdefault:CARD=NVidia
    HDA NVidia, ALC662 rev1 Analog
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, ALC662 rev1 Analog
    Front speakers
surround40:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, ALC662 rev1 Analog
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, ALC662 rev1 Analog
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, ALC662 rev1 Analog
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, ALC662 rev1 Analog
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, ALC662 rev1 Analog
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, ALC662 rev1 Analog
    Direct sample mixing device
dmix:CARD=NVidia,DEV=2
    HDA NVidia, ALC662 rev1 Analog
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, ALC662 rev1 Analog
    Direct sample snooping device
dsnoop:CARD=NVidia,DEV=2
    HDA NVidia, ALC662 rev1 Analog
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, ALC662 rev1 Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=2
    HDA NVidia, ALC662 rev1 Analog
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=0
    HDA NVidia, ALC662 rev1 Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=2
    HDA NVidia, ALC662 rev1 Analog
    Hardware device with all software conversions
sysdefault:CARD=microphone
    ATR USB microphone, USB Audio
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=microphone,DEV=0
    ATR USB microphone, USB Audio
    Front speakers
surround40:CARD=microphone,DEV=0
    ATR USB microphone, USB Audio
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=microphone,DEV=0
    ATR USB microphone, USB Audio
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=microphone,DEV=0
    ATR USB microphone, USB Audio
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=microphone,DEV=0
    ATR USB microphone, USB Audio
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=microphone,DEV=0
    ATR USB microphone, USB Audio
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=microphone,DEV=0
    ATR USB microphone, USB Audio
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
dmix:CARD=microphone,DEV=0
    ATR USB microphone, USB Audio
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=microphone,DEV=0
    ATR USB microphone, USB Audio
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=microphone,DEV=0
    ATR USB microphone, USB Audio
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=microphone,DEV=0
    ATR USB microphone, USB Audio
    Hardware device with all software conversions
```

I've no idea what any of the above means but I was told giving this output would help.

Does anybody have any suggestions of what to do in this situation? If there's something else I can elaborate upon, please tell me and I'll be happy to explain further.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: Here's what I got when I inputted *amixer* into the terminal:

```
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 64
  Mono: Playback 54 [84%] [-10.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Headphone',0
  Capabilities: pswitch penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback [on]
  Front Right: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'PCM',0
  Capabilities: pvolume penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 255
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 254 [100%] [0.20dB]
  Front Right: Playback 254 [100%] [0.20dB]
Simple mixer control 'Front',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 64
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 64 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 64 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Front Mic',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 31
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [off]
  Front Right: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [off]
Simple mixer control 'Front Mic Boost',0
  Capabilities: volume penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: 0 - 3
  Front Left: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'Surround',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 64
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 64 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 64 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Center',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 64
  Mono: Playback 64 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'LFE',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 64
  Mono: Playback 64 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Line',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 31
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [off]
  Front Right: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [off]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958 Default PCM',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'Capture',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch penum
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 31
  Front Left: Capture 11 [35%] [3.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Capture 11 [35%] [3.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Capture',1
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch penum
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 31
  Front Left: Capture 23 [74%] [21.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Capture 23 [74%] [21.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Auto-Mute Mode',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'Disabled' 'Enabled'
  Item0: 'Enabled'
Simple mixer control 'Channel Mode',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: '2ch' '4ch' '6ch'
  Item0: '2ch'
Simple mixer control 'Digital',0
  Capabilities: cvolume penum
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 120
  Front Left: Capture 60 [50%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: Capture 60 [50%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'Input Source',0
  Capabilities: cenum
  Items: 'Rear Mic' 'Front Mic' 'Line'
  Item0: 'Line'
Simple mixer control 'Input Source',1
  Capabilities: cenum
  Items: 'Rear Mic' 'Front Mic' 'Line'
  Item0: 'Front Mic'
Simple mixer control 'Rear Mic',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 31
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 0 [0%] [-34.50dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Rear Mic Boost',0
  Capabilities: volume penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: 0 - 3
  Front Left: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: 0 [0%] [0.00dB]
```